Extension of the base field of an irreducible representation of a finite group stays completely reducible
I was reading chapter $9$ of "Character theory of finite groups" by Isaacs in which he explores the theory of representation of finite groups over arbitrary fields.
In his theorem $(9.2)$, he gives a characterization of absolutely irreducible representations of finite groups $($representations that stays irreducible for every extension of the base field$)$:
For any irreducible representation $V$ over an arbitrary field $F$, $V$ is irreducible iff its endomorphism ring is isomorphic to $F$.
The proof is pretty simple. For any extension $L$ of $F$, $\mathrm{End}_L(V \otimes L) \simeq \mathrm{End}_F(V) \otimes L$. By Maschke theorem, $\mathrm{dim}_L(\mathrm{End}_L(V \otimes L)) = 1$ implies that $V \otimes L$ is irreducible and we're done.
But he doesn't seem to have made any assumption on $F$ in his book, and we know that the Maschke theorem does not hold in general when the characteristic of the field divides the order of the group.
Did i miss a simple argument that proves for example that if $V$ is irreducible, $V \otimes L$ is still at least completely irreducible and that's why we can still apply Maschke theorem ?
He does give another proof by seeing a group representation as the representation of the associated group algebra, using the double centralizer theorem but this theorem also requires the $F[G]$-module $V$ to be completely reducible.
The only reference i found that addresses this question is "Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras" by Curtis and Reiner, in which they show that for a separable field extension, the extension of a completely reducible representation stays completely reducible, but i could not find a counter example.
Do we need to make this assumption for this to work or is there a simpler argument to make this work in the general case ? Is there any known counter example ?

It's true more generally for simple f.d. modules over algebras. See Theorem 7.5 in A First Course in Noncommutative Rings by Lam.
